# Can't start MariaDB suddenly

Tags: mariadb-10.3

```
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.32 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: signal) since Mon 2022-01-31 20:14:00 UTC; 675ms ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 36847 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exite>
    Process: 36859 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exit>
    Process: 36861 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/>
    Process: 36908 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (>
   Main PID: 36908 (code=killed, signal=SEGV)
     Status: "Starting final batch to recover 10 pages from redo log"
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

Comment: Have you been through [What to Do if MariaDB Doesn't Start](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/what-to-do-if-mariadb-doesnt-start/)?

Comment: thank you, that's resolve my problem